# SMTP.starttls() TimeoutError on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, email, smtp, smtplib

Today I have tried to send email with python:

```
import smtplib

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.google.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_FROM_LOGIN = 'sender@gmail.com'
EMAIL_FROM_PASSWORD = 'password'

MESSAGE = 'Hi!'

EMAIL_TO_LOGIN = 'recipient@gmail.com'

print('starting...')
server = smtplib.SMTP(EMAIL_HOST, EMAIL_PORT)
server.starttls()

print('logging...')
server.login(EMAIL_FROM_LOGIN, EMAIL_FROM_PASSWORD)

print('sending message...')
server.sendmail(EMAIL_FROM_LOGIN, EMAIL_TO_LOGIN, MESSAGE)
```

This script doesn't goes further than `starting...` print. I searched about this issue whole day, but found only something like:

> "check that port isn't blocked..."

At least I got info about blocked/disabled/etc. port, what I don't have, is specifics of problem.

---

Additional info: following some of advices I found earlier, I checked output of `telnet smtp.google.com 587`.
The output is static `Connecting to smtp.google.com...`. It remains for like 2 mins, and then prints:

> Could not open a connection to this host, on port 587: Connection failed

---

**UPD 1**

I tried to open ports manually, on which python script has been run, but nothing changes...

---

So, my question is: what should I do? Where I can find those blocked ports, how to unblock/enable them?

Comment: ```server.ehlo()```?

Comment: @Sujay same story

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable lower security in your gmail account and fix your smtp address: '**smtp.gmail.com**':

My sample:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

mail_content = 'Sample text'

sender_address = 'xxx@xxx'
sender_pass = 'xxxx'
receiver_address = 'xxx@xxx'

message = MIMEMultipart()
message['From'] = sender_address
message['To'] = receiver_address
message['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
message.attach(MIMEText(mail_content, 'plain'))

session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
session.starttls()
session.login(sender_address, sender_pass)
session.sendmail(sender_address, receiver_address, message.as_string())
session.quit()

print('Mail Sent')
```

Comment: I'm such a blind idiot...
Changing from `'smtp.google.com'` to `'smtp.gmail.com'` is solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

---

Have you checked your code? there is **smtp.google.com** instead of **smtp.gmail.com**.

Before executing the script

---

1. First of all, ensure that you logged in by that mail you are going to use to send mail in your script.
2. The second thing and important you must have on your [Less Security App](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4NW9JsHpBngFJepAMWVt38ISamxkCE1oZCeN2JLrrJhjrv23mFLGCXpwzF9ZZEqzjykTOjTvr286mEHEyd65j4OHLMpYg) or [2-Step Verification](https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome).

---

Now you can use the following **Python 3 Code** also

---

```
import smtplib as s
obj = s.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587) #smtp server host and port no. 587
obj.starttls() #tls is a way of encryption

obj.login("sender@gmail.com","password")# login credential email and password by which you want to send mail.

subject = "Write your subject" #Subject of mail
message_body = " Hello Dear...\n Write your message here... "

msg = "Subject:{}\n\n{}".format(subject,message_body) #  complete mail subject + message body

list_of_address = ["mail1@gmail.com", "mail2@gmail.com", "mail3@yahoo.com", "mail4@outlook.in"]# list of email address
obj.sendmail("sender@gmail.com", list_of_address, msg)

print("Send Successfully...")
obj.quit()
```

---

Now coming to your second question
**what should I do? Where I can find those blocked ports, how to unblock/enable them?**

**Unblock Ports**

---

**Warning!** Opening or unblocking ports are very dangerous it's like breaking the firewall.
It's up to you to be careful.

---

You can try unblocking the following ports
**80, 433, 443, 3478, 3479, 5060, 5062, 5222, 6250, and 12000-65000.**

---

1. Go to **Control Panel**->Click **System and Security**->Click **Windows Firewall**->Select **Advanced settings**, and then select **Inbound Rules** in the left pane->Right-click **Inbound Rules** and then select **New Rule**->Select **Port**->click **Next**.
2. Select **TCP** as the protocol to apply the rule.
3. Select **Specific Local Ports**, add all the above ports, and then click **Next**.
4. Select **Allow the connection**.
5. Leave **Domain**, **Private**, and **Public** checked to apply the rule to all types of networks.
6. Name the rule something click **Finish**.

---

I hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: **DO NOT** open ports on your firewall as suggested in this answer. It is dangerous. A very bad idea possibly with harmful consequences.